# ASP MVC web config access controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

basically I would like to know is it possible to link to a controller action method through web config?

Example below can direct link to google but i wish it link to my controller action method, is that possible?

```
<add key="return" value="https://www.google.com/" />
```

```
   {
        public PayPalModel(bool useSandbox)
        {
            this.cmd = "_xclick";
            this.business = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["business"];
            this.cancel_return = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cancel_return"];
            this.@return = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["return"];
            if (useSandbox)
            {
                this.actionURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test_url"];
            }
            else
            {
                this.actionURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Prod_url"];
            }

            this.notify_url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["notify_url"];

            this.currency_code = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["currency_code"];
        }        

   }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to configure your routes within the web.config?

Comment: actually this is the paypal implementation, after the paypal payment have been completed, i will read the return url from the web config then the paypal will auto redirect to the read url. It could redirect to google, but i want it redirect to my Home/Index...

Comment: Looks like an AppSettings key/value pair to me. Nothing to do with MVC or anything else. Just custom code using the AppSettings?

Comment: I have edited my question, I should show my model also =)